# Optional columns in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

Recently I started porting ADO.net app to Entity Framework. There are some optional columns in my table. With the ADO.net, I just check for existence of the column and get the value if it is there.

```
if (MyTable.Columns.Contains("PerformPreCheck") &&
    DBNull.Value != MyRow[MyTable.Columns["PerformPreCheck"]])
{
         m_bPerformPreCheck = (bool)MyRow[MyTable.Columns["PerformPreCheck"]];
}
```

How can I achieve the same thing with Entity Framework?

Thank you,
Suresh

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your entity is called `Foo` and the nullable column is called `PerformPreCheck`:

```
using(var context = new MyEntities())
{
    var f = context.Foos.First(); // or context.Foos.Where(foo => foo.Id == someId).First(), etc....
    m_bPerformPreCheck = f.PerformPreCheck.GetValueOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Hi Craig,

Thank you for your reply. In my entity model, I have "PerformPreCheck" check coulumn, but in my customer database they do not have that column as it is optional. It is failing at "var f=context.Foos.First()". But the code ADO.net code I gave above works perfectly. I am trying to find the equivalent of it.

Thank you,
Suresh

Comment: You cannot have a DB schema which changes and an Entity Model which doesn't. You must keep your DB schema and Entity Model in sync.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This could quite happen in the field. To me it is like a limitation. I could do this in ADO.net, no problem. I am regretting now moving to Entity Framework.

Comment: On second thought, you can't do this in EF 1 (easily), but it wouldn't be hard with a code-only model in EF 4. But every ORM is going to require a mapping of some sort which matches your DB schema.

Comment: If your app needs backwards compatibility with older version databases, then don't use any ORM.